# Meta Lost its Offline Page

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, offline

At least in Firefox, Meta is showing StackOverflow's offline page.

**EDIT**: I don't mean that [Meta's page](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/app_offline.htm) is showing the wrong image.
I mean that when Meta is down, it redirects to SO's down page.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/9dCvx/)

Meta's dedicated page is not shown:

[Meta Means Murder http://sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/img/offline-meta-means-murder.png](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/app_offline.htm)

Comment: Works fine here in FF4.

Comment: @marcog: I don't mean in http://sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/app_offline.htm.  I mean when meta is actually down.

Comment: Oh, I see. So it's redirecting to the [wrong page](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/app_offline.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offline page gets no love since it's hardly ever shown.  I have added a few tweaks.

Comment: [You didn't do a very good job](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80917/se-offline-pages-arent-skinned).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to some poorly-written Javascript code in the global SE offline page which tries to redirect to the offline page for the appropriate site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hostHash = new Object();
    var hostName = window.location.hostname;
    var sstaticOffline = 'http://sstatic.net/';
    var returnUrl = window.location;        

    hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'stackoverflowmeta/app_offline.htm'] = 'meta\.stackoverflow';
    hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'stackoverflow/app_offline.htm'] = 'stackoverflow|localhost';
    hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'serverfault/app_offline.htm'] = 'serverfault';
    hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'superuser/app_offline.htm'] = 'superuser';
    hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'nothingtoinstall/app_offline.htm'] = 'nothingtoinstall';
    hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'skins/sketchy/app_offline.htm'] = 'stackexchange';
    hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'stackapps/app_offline.htm'] = 'stackapps';

    for (var entry in hostHash) {            
        var regEx = new RegExp(hostHash[entry]);

        if (regEx.test(hostName)) {                
            window.location = entry + '?return=' + escape(returnUrl);
        }
    }

    $().ready(function () {
        $('#return').attr('href', returnUrl);            
    });

</script>
```

The problem is that setting `window.location` doesn't immediately stop the script.
Therefore, after matching `meta\.stackoverflow`, it will go on to match `stackoverflow|localhost` and redirect to SO's offline page.

Answer (score 0):

The code also has three other issues:

Since the strings in `hotHash` are strings and not regex literals, the `\` escape in `meta\.stackoverflow` is swallowed by the string literal.
They should be regex literals.

http://sstatic.net/nothingtoinstall/app_offline.htm 404's.
However, that codepath is never taken anyway.

There is nothing to match `askubuntu.com`.