# SE Offline Pages aren't skinned

Tags: bug, status-completed, offline

The App_Offline page for every new SE site except AskUbuntu don't redirect to the Sketchy offline page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be watching for the next offline event to test.

Answer (score 2):

This bug is caused by the following code:

```
var hostHash = new Object();
var hostName = window.location.hostname;
var sstaticOffline = 'http://sstatic.net/';
var returnUrl = window.location;        

function goOffline() {
    hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'stackoverflowmeta/app_offline.htm'] = 'meta\.stackoverflow';
    hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'stackoverflow/app_offline.htm'] = 'stackoverflow';
    hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'serverfault/app_offline.htm'] = 'serverfault';
    hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'superuser/app_offline.htm'] = 'superuser';
    hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'skins/sketchy/app_offline.htm'] = 'stackexchange';
    hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'stackapps/app_offline.htm'] = 'stackapps';
    hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'skins/sketchy/app_offline.htm'] = 'askubuntu';

    for (var entry in hostHash) {            
        var regEx = new RegExp(hostHash[entry]);

        if (regEx.test(hostName)) {
            window.location = entry + '?return=' + escape(returnUrl);    
            return;           
        }
    }
}

$().ready(function () {
    goOffline();
    $('#return').attr('href', returnUrl);
});
```

Specifically, it's caused by the two lines

```
hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'skins/sketchy/app_offline.htm'] = 'stackexchange';
...
hostHash[sstaticOffline + 'skins/sketchy/app_offline.htm'] = 'askubuntu';
```

It tries to set two different values to the same key, so the `'stackexchange'` value is overwritten.